# How to change counting label text in Swift 5

Tags: swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var flipCount = 0

    @IBAction func card1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flipCount += 1
        flipCard(emoje: "☠️" , button: sender)
    } 

    @IBAction func card2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flipCount += 1
        flipCard(emoje: "", button: sender)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var counter: UILabel!
}
```

How can I link my counter to my UI? I can't put `flipcountLabel.text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you can simply update the `UI with flipCount` by adding a **`property observer`** to the `flipCount`, i.e.

```
var flipCount = 0 {
    didSet {
        counter.text = String(flipCount)
    }
}
```

In the above code, the `counter label` will be updated with the latest `flipCount` value whenever there is a change in `flipCount`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `UILabel` instance `counter`

```
@IBAction func card1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    flipCount += 1
    counter.text = \(flipCount)
    flipCard(emoje: "☠️" , button: sender)
} 

@IBAction func card2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    flipCount += 1
    counter.text = \(flipCount)
    flipCard(emoje: "", button: sender)
}
```